# How can I change the default editor for OS X on install?

Tags: macos, installation, file-association

I'm setting up an app to install on OS X. Previous versions of this app have been installed, and have associated a file type to open with the app in the Info.plist file in the app bundle. I have the same associations in the Info.plist for the new version of the app. I'd like to change the default app on install to use the new version without requiring the user to un-install their old version, or manually change the association in the Open With... dialog.

Is this possible, to somehow register my app to now be the default edtior for this filetype, even when a default editor exists?

It's just for a file type specific to the app, so I don't think it'd be annoying or unethical to change the association when I install the new app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) works in snow leopard, but I know I've used it in older versions of os x.

A nice blog entry about it can be found [here](http://apcmag.com/how_to_set_your_default_applications_in_mac_os_x.htm) as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to set the default app on install of a program, not set my preferences as a user.

Comment: Ah, afaik, that's only found in the Info.plist.  I think the most recent app scanned get's precedence, but I'm not 100% sure.